# Question with capture packets from PPP interface

Tags: c, networking, ubuntu, libpcap

I am using libpcap to capture data from PPP interface, and add filter as follow:

```
char filter_exp[] = "ip";
```

But when i sniff the packets in callback function, I found that the format of ip packet is

not correct, the header size is not 20 byte.

And when I capture packets from eth0, everything is normal.

So who can tell me how to get the correct ip packets from PPP interface by libpcap, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But when i sniff the packets in callback function, I found that the format of ip packet is not correct, the header size is not 20 byte.

Your callback function is using the results of a `pcap_datalink()` call on the `pcap_t` to determine how to parse the packets, or you've specified different callback functions depending on the results of `pcap_datalink()`, right?

If not, you are probably assuming that the packets will have a particular link-layer header type, which is always the wrong thing to do.

PPP packets won't necessarily have the same link-layer header type as Ethernet packets (although on Windows with WinPcap, they might have the same link-layer header type!).  They might not have a PPP header, either; in particular, on Linux, they will have a [Linux cooked capture header](http://www.tcpdump.org/linktypes/LINKTYPE_LINUX_SLL.html) because, at least at one point, the *kernel* would strip the PPP header and supply *no* link-layer header, so libpcap had to do a "cooked" capture in order to be able to get the network-layer protocol type.  `pcap_datalink()` will return `DLT_LINUX_SLL`, not `DLT_PPP`, for PPP devices on Linux, to indicate this.

Answer (score 0):

PPP and IP are completely different protocols.  If you're transferring IP datagrams over PPP then you're wrapping them in the PPP header with the IP packet as the payload.  You'll need to strip the PPP information from the packet before it's an IP packet.

Comment: I think libpcap strips PPP header automatic when i add the filter "ip"